# Application architecture using my own class

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is the first time I would like to implement MongoDB as a database within one of my applications and I’m quite confused...
My application has its own User class which is represented at the end of this post(UML class diagram).

Since my User object has its own properties and methods I feel that creating a schema usually used with mongoose would mean duplicating code.

Am I really well understanding how MongoDB works?
Is it not possible to save my User object inside my MongoDB database without having to use a schema?
If I want to follow the MVC pattern how could I implement the MongoDB model with the class represented on my diagram?

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: You can remove the `current user class` and create a schema with the same properties. Instead of using the `current user class`, use the `MongoDB schema`.

Comment: That could be a suitable option! But is it really following the MVC pattern putting the logic business of my class inside my model file?

Comment: In this context, your `MongoDB Schema` be your `Model` in `MVC patterns`. I hope someone will come up with a better solution.